# RTX 3080 not much faster than GTX 1650 Ti with CUDA 11.3 in pytorch?

Tags: python, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

so I have two GPUs on different machines:

- GTX 1650 Ti: 4  GB, 1024 CUDA cores, in a notebook
- RTX 3080:    10 GB, 8960 CUDA cores, in a desktop

I am using them to train deep learning models with PyTorch. For both, I set up a conda PyTorch environment with CUDA 11.3 toolkit. Originally, I expected that the RTX would deliver manifold speedup over the GTX. However, I quickly noticed that the RTX "only" seems to perform twice as fast as GTX. I really am not sure how much to expect here, but it would be a bit disappointing to just have a twofold speedup, given its an RTX vs an onboard notebook graphics card ^^. According to gpu.userbenchmark.com (and in general), the RTX should play in a totally different league than the GTX. See this excerpt comparison (where left is the GTX and RTX is right):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXaag.png

Here is some short benchmark code, according to an example in the pytorch docs:

```python
import torch
print(torch.__version__)
print(torch.version.cuda)

def batched_dot_mul_sum(a, b):
    '''Computes batched dot by multiplying and summing'''
    return a.mul(b).sum(-1)

def batched_dot_bmm(a, b):
    '''Computes batched dot by reducing to bmm'''
    a = a.reshape(-1, 1, a.shape[-1])
    b = b.reshape(-1, b.shape[-1], 1)
    return torch.bmm(a, b).flatten(-3)

# Input for benchmarking
x = torch.randn(10000, 64, device='cuda')

# Ensure that both functions compute the same output
assert batched_dot_mul_sum(x, x).allclose(batched_dot_bmm(x, x))

import torch.utils.benchmark as benchmark

t0 = benchmark.Timer(
    stmt='batched_dot_mul_sum(x, x)',
    setup='from __main__ import batched_dot_mul_sum',
    globals={'x': x})

t1 = benchmark.Timer(
    stmt='batched_dot_bmm(x, x)',
    setup='from __main__ import batched_dot_bmm',
    globals={'x': x})

print(t0.timeit(100000))
print(t1.timeit(100000))
```

The output is as follows:

- GTX:

```
1.10.2
11.3
<torch.utils.benchmark.utils.common.Measurement object at 0x000001F7518E8C40>
batched_dot_mul_sum(x, x)
setup: from __main__ import batched_dot_mul_sum
  72.80 us
  1 measurement, 100000 runs , 1 thread
<torch.utils.benchmark.utils.common.Measurement object at 0x000001F7518E8D90>
batched_dot_bmm(x, x)
setup: from __main__ import batched_dot_bmm
  70.01 us
  1 measurement, 100000 runs , 1 thread
```

- RTX:

```
1.10.2
11.3
<torch.utils.benchmark.utils.common.Measurement object at 0x000001AF2F63F5E0>
batched_dot_mul_sum(x, x)
setup: from __main__ import batched_dot_mul_sum
  29.88 us
  1 measurement, 100000 runs , 1 thread
<torch.utils.benchmark.utils.common.Measurement object at 0x000001AF26F99B20>
batched_dot_bmm(x, x)
setup: from __main__ import batched_dot_bmm
  27.02 us
  1 measurement, 100000 runs , 1 thread
```

As we see, there is a speedup of only a bit more than twice when using the RTX, which seems not that much (?). Thus, I might be doing sth wrong that causes the performance of the RTX not to be fully utilized.

The RTX came with CUDA 11.6 installed. The latest conda PyTorch distribution goes only to 11.3, but there is the possibility to install a pytorch CUDA 11.6 version with nightly binaries:

```
pip install torch --pre --extra-index-URL https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cu116
```

Using this environment, the corresponding output of the benchmark script (RTX with Cuda 11.6) is:

```
1.13.0.dev20220528+cu116
11.6
<torch.utils.benchmark.utils.common.Measurement object at 0x0000011A24BC6100>
batched_dot_mul_sum(x, x)
setup: from __main__ import batched_dot_mul_sum
  22.96 us
  1 measurement, 100000 runs , 1 thread
<torch.utils.benchmark.utils.common.Measurement object at 0x0000011A15803B50>
batched_dot_bmm(x, x)
setup: from __main__ import batched_dot_bmm
  21.88 us
  1 measurement, 100000 runs , 1 thread
```

So, there is just little additional speedup, depending on the CUDA version. Overall, the advantage of the RTX over the GTX seems poor, especially given that one of them is an onboard notebook graphics and the other is an actual device.

Another option would be to build PyTorch with cuda 11.6 from source. Maybe, only then, the performance of the RTX can be fully utilized? I have avoided this option so far, as the nightly binaries option was available. Would it make a difference to build from the source? Maybe this is the cause of the problem. Otherwise, I do not really have any idea what could be the cause of the slow performance of the RTX, compared to the GTX :(.

Thanks, best, JZ

Comment: I can't tell from your code if you are running 100,000 threads at the same time, which would make better use of the 8 times as many shaders, or if they are literally running 100,000 sequentially which is what I suspect `timeit` is doing and would only really test a single shader at a time. An individual shader unit being 2-2.5 times faster would be an impressive generational improvement but you need to be certain you are using the nearly 9 times as many shaders which I'm not convinced your benchmark is doing.

Comment: In addition to answering the above comment, try to [disable tf32](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cuda.html#tf32-on-ampere).

Comment: you mean disabling the tf32, in order to make the benchmark comparison fairer?

Comment: i honestly do not know how i would determine whether the threads are run in parallel. if it helps, the code above is the only thing i execute. if you know how to adapt it to ensure that the threads are run in parallel, i could execute it and see whether it changes anything in the timing. as you say, I also suspect that the timing is done sequentially, though. edit: if i increase the number of iterations, the time to compute actually linearly increases, so sequentially seems to be the case.

Comment: another edit concerning tf32: edit: i set the flags ```torch.backends.cuda.matmul.allow_tf32, torch.backends.cudnn.allow_tf32``` both to false. it does not change anything in the timing.